# How to get autocompletion with TAB to work on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris-10

I have just installed a Solaris 10 virtualbox and <kbd>TAB</kbd> autocompletion is not working. People seem to suggest that it is shell specific. Any particular suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way:

```
>tcsh
>set autolist
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> should work from there on in your terminal.
Still happy to see other solutions here as well.